# Pass options using element attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Imagine the following construct:

```
<div id="slider" value="35" max="97"/>
<script>$("#slider").slider();</script>
```

Would be nice if one can make that work? I.e. instead of passing options to "slider(...)" I'd like pass the options as attributes to the target element.

dero

Comment: Just set the options as custom `data-*` attributes - pull the values out, then use them in the `slider()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming .slider() accepts an object for those variables, you can set them as a data on the element for jQuery to pick up.

```
<div id="slider" data-slider='{"value": "35", "max": "97"}'/>

$("#slider").each(function(){
    $(this).slider($(this).data('slider'));
});
```

NB the data must be valid JSON